# PHP dropdown search result selecting wrong input

Tags: php

I have made a dropdown search form that is auto populated by my database content. The voices in the table would be for example types of woods with varing dimensions.
So there are repeatable wood names with diverse data.
To avoid repetition the dropdown is populated with wood types combined to be selected then displayed with all their variants.
The problem is, upon selecting an input, the results are of the item listed above and not the one selected.

```
<form action="search2.php" method="POST">
    <select name="finit"  onchange='this.form.submit()'>
      <?php
      include("connect.php");
      $query = "SELECT finit FROM prime";
      $info = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
      $finit = '';

         echo "<option value=\"\">Selezione Materiale</option>";
        while($row = $info->fetch_assoc()){
if($row['finit'] != $finit) {
    echo "<option value=\"$finit\">" . $row['finit'] . "</option>";
    $finit = $row['finit']; 
                            } 
    } 
       ?>
    </select>
    <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
  </form>
```

Comment: Hi @jj jones, I don't understand the result you want to get, can you show us an example?

Comment: From my code I get my database results to populate a table without a problem. The problem is that the selected voice within the dropdown does not send the same to the table. It sends the voice above the dropdown list to the table

Comment: You are setting the option text to `$row['finit']`, but the option value (which is what will get submitted) to `$finit` - and you only assign `$finit = $row['finit']` _after_ you created the option, so of course this “lags behind” by one each time …

Comment: Thank you misorude. I put it before and the code is working properly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are many variants(dimensions) associated with a single wood type, you have to first take the wood type as input from user(via dropdown list), and probably then you may want to display all possible variants(dimensions) of that particular wood type.

So, change the SQL query in the following way,

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT finit FROM prime";
```

and the `while` loop in the following way,

```
while($row = $info->fetch_assoc()){
    $output = "<option value='" . $row['finit'] . "'";
    if($row['finit'] == $_POST['finit']){
        $output .= " selected='selected'";
    }
    $output .= ">" . $row['finit'] . "</option>";
    echo $output;
}
```

Comment: @jjjones Glad I could help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this but change if condition according your default value and sql value should be match.

```
    <form action="search2.php" method="POST">
        <select name="finit"  onchange='this.form.submit()'>
          <?php
          include("connect.php");
          $query = "SELECT finit FROM prime";
          $info = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
          $finit = '';
        ?>
            <option value="">Selezione Materiale</option>;
            <?php
            while($row = $info->fetch_assoc()){
                    if($row['finit'] == $finit) {
                        $selected = 'selected'; 
                    }else{
                        $selected = ''; 
$finit = $row['finit']; 
                    }  
           ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $finit ?>" <?php echo $selected ?>><?php echo $row['finit']?></option>
           <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
      </form>
```